# Планирование задач для разработки

Tags: веб-программирование, планировщик-задач

я веб-разработчик, сейчас занимаюсь разработкой крупного проекта, проект уже длится около года, предположительно работы еще на год-два.

Весь процесс разработки сводится к тому, что мне из разных источников капают задачи:

1. Задачи может ставить тестировщик.
2. Задачи ставит менеджер.
3. Задачи ставит сам клиент (как новые задачи, так и доработки).
4. Задачи могу ставить я сам себе (доработать какой-то функционал, пофиксить баги и т.д.).

Сейчас нет единого источника поступления задач, задачи ставятся по почте, в скайпе, либо устно - на словах говорят и т.д.

Эти все задачи должен контролировать я, вести статусы задач.

**Что мне нужно в идеале**

Иметь единую систему, куда я бы мог заносить свои задачи, указывать им трудозатраты, менять статусы и устанавливать сколько часов проработано по той или иной задачи.
Трудозатраты должны суммироваться, и я должен в итоге видеть, предстоящий объем работ. 
Также клиент в любой момент может запросить план на ближайшую неделю/месяц, чтобы понимать какие задачи будут выполняться.

В любой момент может прилететь задача, к которой нужно приступить **сейчас**, соответственно задачу нужно ввести в систему, а все остальные задачи должны сдвинуться вниз.

**Какие системы я пробовал, и что мне не понравилось**

1. Bitrix24-Задачи - система очень медленная, неудобная, нет возможности устанавливать трудозатраты к задачи и видеть объем работ.
2. Trello - нравится все. только также нет возможность ставить трудозатраты к задаче. Вероятно, есть какие-то платные дополнения, но я не смог поставить демо версию, чтобы посмотреть.
3. MS Project - все классно, то что надо, только очень сложно вставить какую-то задачу в середину, т.к. всем последующим задачам нужно менять зависимости.

Какими системами пользуетесь вы? Какие инструменты используете? Как решаете подобные задачи?

Comment: Atlassian Jira, вряд ли есть альтернативы

Comment: юзали  Gemini для маленькой команды. раньше было бесплатно, если меньше 6 человек, счас не знаю. вполне себе современная штука, но на c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я поделюсь соображениями, которые позволят вам уточнить пожелания к системе, и может быть даже немного их изменят.

Программисты любят разнообразный учёт и контроль, и любят системы учёта. Сколько я знаю программистов, все предпочитают как-то формализовать работу. В подавляющем большинстве случаев подход с наскока не работает, потому что в начале это несколько общих принципов, которые быстро обрастают множеством исключений. Учёт начинает требовать всё больше сил и времени, и в конце концов забрасывается, потому что становится непосильной ношей.

Но учёт и планирование действительно важны, поэтому учитывать надо, но подходить к нему со стороны ресурсов. Если у вас большая компания, распределённые команды, то с помощью людей и денег можно делать видео-конференции, вести задачи в сложных системах с большим количеством параметров, и строить разные графики.

Но если у вас небольшая команда или вы один, то вам подойдёт любая бесплатная система. Джоэл Спольски [пишет](http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8C%D1%8E), что планировать можно даже в Excel. Ну, в наше время речь идёт о таблице в Google Docs.

Я лично рекомендую объединить репозиторий кода с простым трекером, и разместить проект в github.com или bitbucket.org. В обеих системах есть возможность делать закрытые проекты, их код недоступен снаружи.

В Самаре живёт программист Максим Догонов, который поднимает и развивает российский аналог GitHub, проект gitbranch.ru. Я не проверял, есть ли там закрытые репозитории, но если есть, вы можете разместить свой проект и там.

Трекеры в этих системах весьма просты, и всех ваших потребностей не покроют. И, возможно, дело не в трекерах, а в потребностях. Большинство этих потребностей обусловлены не необходимостью, а тягой программиста к формализации.

Для реальных результатов они не нужны.

В трекере GitHub вы можете создавать *этапы* (mile stones) — даты, к которым нужно сделать определённый объём работ. В гибких методологиях используют *итерации* или *спринты* продолжительностью неделя, две недели, месяц, чтобы отслеживать развитие проекта. Эту практику вы можете перенять, и делать этапы работ, например, по две недели.

В трекере GitHub есть *метки* (labels), которые вы можете назначать задачам. Эти метки вы можете создавать самостоятельно. Каждой задаче можно назначить несколько меток. Будьте осторожны, появится искушение сделать пятьдесят меток, и назначать их по десятку на каждую задачу. Это дорога в никуда.

В трекере GitHub нет оценки задач в часах и даже в попугаях. Возможно, она и не нужна. Несколько соображений на этот счёт. Спольски пишет, и подобную мысль я ещё где-то слышал, что мы можем точно оценить только небольшие задачи. Условная граница — один рабочий день, 8 часов. Если речь идёт о трёх днях или о неделе, точность вполне может составить до ста процентов, и задача может быть сделана не за неделю, а за две.

Поэтому сложные задачи надо *декомпозировать* до приемлемого уровня сложности и продолжительности. Два основных уровня, с которыми работают программисты, это *пользовательские истории* и *задачи*. Пользовательская история это способ представления технического задания, разработанный в *экстремальном программировании*. Предполагается, что такая задача может быть сделана в рамках одного этапа, то есть занимает не больше двух недель. Её надо разбить на *задачи* продолжительностью от часа до восьми. Обычно речь идёт об *идеальных* часах, то есть часах продуктивной работы, когда вы энергичны и вас не отвлекают. Так бывает редко, поэтому я ограничиваюсь 1, 2 и 4 часами.

Кажется, что это слишком грубая детализация. Но грустная правда состоит в том, что даже с самой точной детализацией до минуты, точность прогнозирования будет составлять 60-80%, при этом у вас регулярно будут встречаться задачи, в которых прогноз будет отличаться не просто в разы (сотни процентов), а в десятки раз (тысячи процентов).

Уровень сложности над пользовательскими историями — это *функции* (features). Обычно на этот уровне с вами разговаривает заказчик. Он говорит: я хочу, чтобы пользователи вводили логин/пароль. Вы записываете в трекер пункт **Реализовать авторизацию пользователей** и ставите ему метку *функция*. Сколько времени она займёт? Неизвестно. Для начала декомпозируем до историй. Должна быть форма авторизации. Запишем историю **Пользователь авторизуется на сайте**. Но, чтобы авторизоваться, пользователь должен быть зарегистрирован. **Пользователь регистрируется на сайте**. Если есть пользователи, то администратор должен ими управлять. **Администратор назначает права пользователю**. У вас получится несколько историй, в данном случае порядка десяти.

Далее вы декомпозируете истории до задач, которые можно оценить в часах. В самой первой истории вам потребуется создать в базе таблицу. Вы думаете на этом этапе, что это будет за таблица и можете даже в задаче указать названия и типы полей.

**Создать миграцию в базе данных для хранения логинов и паролей пользователей**.

На уровне бизнес-логики вы реализуете *репозиторий пользователей*, класс *пользователь* и, например, *службу авторизации*. **Реализовать класс пользователь**, **Реализовать репозиторий пользователей**, **Реализовать службу авторизации**.

Эти конкретные задачи вы можете оценивать в часах. Все эти задачи будет видеть ваш заказчик, и будет понимать, что именно вы делаете.

Обычно декомпозиция занимает 20% времени от всего этапа, но может быть и больше, если задачи незнакомые. Если задачи совсем незнакомые, лучше запланировать исследовательскую работу. Если вы работаете двухнедельными итерациями, а это десять рабочих дней, то планирование занимает два дня.

Не обязательно декомпозировать сразу всё. Если вы видите, что задач набирается до конца этапа, можно остановиться.

Для решения приоритетных задач может завести специальную метку. Если приходит *срочная* задача, вы включаете её в этап, и переносите на следующий этап часть запланированной работы.

Вы можете сделать метки *feature*, *story*, *task1*, *task2*, *task4* и *urgent*. Метка *bug* уже есть в GitHub, отдельно её создавать не надо.

С ошибками история отдельная. Очень редко кода мы можем оценить время, которое потребуется на исправление ошибки. Иногда даже близко не ясно, откуда она берётся. Ошибки просто записывайте и исправляйте, начиная с самых неприятных. Можете где-то отмечать временные затраты. Но для вашего проекта, где вы один, сильно не заморачивайтесь.

Если вы один, то вам тратить на учёт более 2-3-5% своего рабочего времени это непроизводительные траты.

Comment: Спасибо большое!
Заинтересовала статья Джоэль Спольски, прочитал, увидел в этом свою проблематику и решение.
Действительно, все оказывается на много проще,
Excel - это то, что решает все мои задачи, его можно как угодно подстроить, добавить любые поля, строить графики, при необходимости подключить Power BI.

Answer (score 0):

Как это часто бывает, готовой системы, которая бы полностью удовлетворила Ваши запросы, скорее всего не существует.

Все коробочные и облачные решения включают только наиболее востребованный функционал, т.к. они рассчитаны на широкую аудиторию, а угодить каждому, сами понимаете, не реально. Рабочий процесс везде так или иначе индивидуален.

Наиболее продвинутая (из моего субъективного опыта) Atlassian Jira, но она платная. И не факт, что даже она в чистом виде Вас устроит и Вам не придётся её дополнять какими-нибудь плагинами.

Поэтому ИМХО самый лучший способ - попробовать несколько вариантов и выбрать наиболее подходящий.

Answer (score 0):

### Многопользовательское решение

Можете попробовать OTRS, она бесплатная, под лицензией GNU GPL v3. Заточена прежде всего под взаимодействие с заявками, поступающими извне (ну и создаваемые внутри, конечно же). Можно указывать трудозатраты, ставить сроки, важность и т.п. Планировать объём работ. Назначать ответственного, надзирателя и исполнителя. Строить отчёты, настраивать очереди, доступа и т.п. Подробнее об основах https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITIL.

Скачать: https://github.com/OTRS/otrs

### Режим "одиночка"

Консольная программа под названием https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taskwarrior, очень умный простой список задач, который также умеет вычислять трудозатраты, важность, начало и окончание работ. Но тут без GUI, если не боитесь.